# Ember bind attribute using truth helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I'm using Ember v1.13 and would like to render the `checked` attribute of an `input` element based on the result of an [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) expression. The following **DID NOT** work for me:

```
<input type="radio" checked={{(eq arg1 arg2)}}>

<input type="radio" checked={{if (eq arg1 arg2) true false}}>
```

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to resort to the following (which works)?

```
  {{#if (eq arg1 arg2)}}
      <input type="radio" checked>
  {{else}}
      <input type="radio">
  {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" checked={{eq arg1 arg2}}>
```

Or better, use `{{input}}` helper:

```
{{input type='radio' checked=(eq arg1 arg2)}}
```